# How to Handle Favourite button clicks in custom Tableview cells iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I am developing one app and i have one requirement that. I have to handle the Favourite button on custom cells like. i am creating the custom button with image on cell and setting unselected type Favourite image i am giving by default once user click on the Favourite button on cell i am changing the button image like selected favourite. I am using the following code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @“CustomCell”;
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.section;
    [cell.favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFavouriteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}
```

Button Action:

```
-(void)handleFavouriteButton:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = sender;
    NSLog(@"selected favourite button tag %li", (long)button.tag);

    if (button.selected) {
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else{
       [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    button.selected=!button.selected;
}
```

Using the above code i am able to change the change the Favourite button from normal to selected and selected to normal but problem is when i select the favourite button on first row it is changing 6 and 11 Ect.. rows also.
Can anybody suggest me right way to do this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That button action and all things are looks fine. You need to save selected Button index as a tag in to the NSMutableArray like following example:

**In.h Class:**

```
interface myclass : UIViewController{
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrcontainstate;
```

**In.m Class:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _arrcontainstate=[NSMutableArray array];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @“CustomCell”;
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.row;
            if ( [_arrcontainstate containsObject:indexPath.row]) {
                   [cell.favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            else {
                [cell.favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }

    [cell.favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFavouriteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}

-(void)handleFavouriteButton:(id)sender
{
 UIButton *button = sender;
 button.selected=!button.selected;
    NSLog(@"selected favourite button tag %li", (long)button.tag);

    if (button.selected) {
         [_arrcontainstate addObject:button.tag];
         [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-Selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
       [_arrcontainstate removeObject:button.tag];
       [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
}
```

Comment: @nitin its working fine...but when we scrolls it changes states....so how to solve it

Comment: if you notice and check cellForRowindex code i used "if ( [_arrcontainstate containsObject:indexPath.row]) {" that means if your idexPath and already contain in arraContainInstate then that you sould set status i mean set fevorites image

Answer (score 0):

As you are reusing the cell, the image of the button is not changing. First cell is reused in 6th and 11th cell so the button image remains selected. Use this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @“CustomCell”;
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.favButton.tag = indexPath.section;
    [cell.favButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favourites-normal.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.favButton addTarget:self action:@selector(handleFavouriteButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i am setting the image to button on storyboard. But once i click on favourite button in first row. Button image changing in first row, 6th and 11 th row as well

Comment: @user1915706 > Don't set image through storyboard.